# Outputting code to a .txt

Tags: c++

I was wondering how to output all this code to a .txt file. When I replace outFile with cout in like 80, I get the output I want (month and balance up to 61 months). However, when I try and put it into the .txt file all I get is a 
"   62       -11.90"

```
int main()
{
    int counts, month=1;
    double totalBalance, interestRate, minimumPayment, sumOfInterest= 0, minPayment, monthInterest;

    input(counts, totalBalance, interestRate, minimumPayment);


    while(totalBalance > 0)
    {
        calculate(month, totalBalance, interestRate, minimumPayment, minPayment, monthInterest, sumOfInterest);
         sumOfInterest = sumOfInterest + sumOfInterest;
         month ++;
        output(month, totalBalance, interestRate, minimumPayment, minPayment, monthInterest, sumOfInterest);
    }

}

void output(int mont, double totalBalanc, double interestRat, double minimumPaymen, double minPaymen, double monthInteres, double sumOfInteres)
{
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("lab6.txt");
    outFile << setw(5) << right << mont << setw(13) << right << setprecision(2) << fixed << totalBalanc << endl;
}
```

Comment: might need to close the file so the runtime flushes the buffers?  `outFile.close()`

Comment: @lock - The destructor will close the file, so not a problem.

Comment: Maybe in the whole code there's an exit() call before the end of the scope holding the `std::ofstream`?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you open the file, it starts writing from the beginning of the file.

Check the optional [`open mode parameter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/open) for other options, like `ate`.

Comment: Ha!  I must've looked at this for an hour.  Sometimes it's the simplest things.    I need to file that away: when the stream acts different from the file, it's the implicit seek that happens with open/close.  I wish I could give a second upvote for concision.